# how to store nodes in sequence?

Tags: neo4j, data-modeling

I am using neo4j 2.1.5 and tying to model a scenario where nodes are video-links and they fall under multiple categories and subcategories, however these nodes will also form a ordered sequence under a particular sequence-category.
e.g;

```
Sequence 1: (node 1)-[:relatedTo]->(node 2)->[:relatedTo]->(node 3)-[:relatedTo]->(node 4)
```

`Sequence 2: (node 2)-[:someRel]->(node 8)->[:someRel]->(node 4)`

What should be the best way to model this?
Note: more video nodes will be added in a sequence-category between the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you've done this looks fine to me.  A set of nodes, with relationships between them, essentially forming a queue.    What you're doing here is basically using neo4j to model a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Linkage to the category is probably where it's going to get interesting.  With linked lists, running through them is easy, but random access (jumping into the middle) is hard.  Now, if the order were always fixed, you could just add a `seq` attribute to your relationships, and label them numerically (0, 1, 2...).   You could then jump in anywhere by querying for the appropriate `seq` value.   *BUT*, if you're saying you want to do dynamic insertions into the list, this is probably a terrible idea.  If you create a new #3, that means you have to increment all subsequent `seq` numbers.  So that's probably not going to work.

Probably just a `Category` node that is always guaranteed to link to the first item in the sequence is a good way to go, like this:

```
(c:Category {name:"Horror"})-[:contains]->(v1:Video {name: "Texas Chainsaw Massacre"})-[:next]->(v2:Video { name: "Hellraiser"});
```

You can do as many `:next` relationships as you want.   To insert something new, you might do this:

```
MATCH (v1:Video {name: "Texas Chainsaw Massacre"})-[r:next]->(v2:Video {name: "Hellraiser"})
CREATE v1-[:next]->(v3:Video {name: "New Thing I'm inserting"}-[:next]->v2
DELETE r;
```

An alternative is that you could link the category to every video (not just the first).  Your videos would still have ordering, and you'd be able to jump into them with random access by video name, but you wouldn't know where the head of your list was anymore.

Comment: Thnx.there is more interesting thing in this scenario,the video will not be a part of just 1 sequenced category & every category may or may not have a section & sub-section(seq.),so it looks like; (category1)-[:contains]->(video1)-[:next]->(video2); (category2)-[:hasSection]->(section1)-[:next]->(section2)-[:hasVideo]->(video3)-[:next]->(video4) & added a property categoryName in [:next] relationship which will identify the category which it belongs to.If there is sub-section then (category2)-[:hasSection]->(section1)-[:hasSubSection]->(section3)-[:hasVideo]->(video2)-[:next]->(video3)